# Replace a string in java, whitespace independent

Tags: java, string, replace, whitespace

I need to replace a string, using java, but the problem is that the search string can have more or less whitespace then the original string.

So let's say we search for

```
"find   me"
```

it should match any of these:

```
- "find me"
- "find       me"
- "find \n\r me"
- "find \t me"
```

Reason for this is that the search string comes from a jsoup element innerhtml() that has logic for inserting whitespace.

Sure, using some smart regex can do the trick, but then we must securely escape regex-chars from the search-string (which is not garanteed to be just a simple alphanum-string, like what if search-string is 'abc?def')

Also, replacing all double whitespace from the input beforehand is not an option.

Comment: Can you give us context for where/how you are doing the matching?

Comment: What @khelwood said. Also, look at [`Pattern.quote()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote-java.lang.String-), this does the required escaping for you.

Comment: You can start by using `.text()` instead of `.html()` in order to get a normalized-spaces string.

Comment: This is not a "why isn't this code working?" question, so the close reason does not apply. (voting to reopen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Sure, using some smart regex can do the trick, but then we must securely escape regex-chars from the search-string (which is not garanteed to be just a simple alphanum-string, like what if search-string is 'abc?def')

That's exactly what I would do:

- split the search string on whitespace
- escape each element using `Pattern.quote(...)`
- rejoin the elements with `\\s+` in between

Example:

```
String searchRegex = Arrays.stream( searchString.split( "\\s+" ) )
                           .map( s -> Pattern.quote( s ) )
                           .collect( Collectors.joining( "\\s+" ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach here would be to trim both the search and target strings, and then normalize all remaining whitespace:

```
boolean match(String input, String term) {
    if (input == null || term == null) {
        return false;
    }

    String s1 = input.trim().replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
    String s2 = term.trim().replaceAll("\\s+", " ");

    return s1.equals(s2);
}
```